# tabla html php while

Tags: php, html, mysql, table, salto-de-linea

tengo horas tratando de resolver esto y no puedo hacer que funcione

tengo varias tablas donde hago consultas y las quiero mostrar en una tabla de html , es facil cuando solo se buscan los datos de una fecha , pero cuando busco dentro de un rango de fechas , es donde se complica.

asi es como debe de quedar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando busco un rango de fechas las filas se mueven de lugar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo pronto este es mi codigo pero creo que el problema esta dentro de un while

1.- se saca cuantos en que dias voy a buscar informacion
2.- despues de tener los dias hago un foreach para cada dia
3.- despues de tener el dia consulto cada hora dependiendo de un array y llevo un contador de array por medio de una variable $i que voy a estar incrementando cada ve que termine el recorrer el array de horas (i2)
4.-una vez que tengo la primer hora del array pongo unos encabezados
5.-hago la consulta de esa hora en 2 tablas diferentes en un query de sumatoria
6.-muestro los resultados de las consultas en un tabla html

```
<?php
$fechadelwhile =  array();
// Aqui saco las fechas en columna y de la fehca en la variable $fechadelwhile para ser utilizada despues
$sql_traerdias = "SELECT desfase FROM `produccion` WHERE desfase BETWEEN \"$fechainicial\" AND \"$fechafinal\" GROUP BY desfase ORDER BY desfase ASC ";
    $tabladias = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql_traerdias);
    while($row0 = mysqli_fetch_array($tabladias))
{ // esta llave abre el while principal
array_push($fechadelwhile , $row0['desfase']);
}// esta llave cierra el while principal
?>
<tr> <!-- abro renglon -->
<?php   
$i = 0; //inicializico en el valor de la llave en 0
while ($i < $contadorarray ) 
{ // esta llave abre donde el recorredor de hora
        $i2 = $turno1horas[$i];
        $i3 = $turnoarray[$i];
foreach ($fechadelwhile as $valor) 
    {
        if($i == 0 )
        {
        ?>
    <tr>
    <th style="width:20%;font-size:20px;" ></th>    
    <th style="width:8%;font-size:20px;" colspan="9"><?php echo $valor ?></th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>Turno Hora</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Produccion</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Calidad</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Diagnostico</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Materiales</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Soporte produccion</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Sumatoria</b>  </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Tress</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Delta</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC  % Delta</b> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
    // lee todas las horas de la fecha , turno , cuadrante , turno y hora sea igual al array dependiedo del turno
    // la variable valor tiene la fecha     
    $sql_produccion = "SELECT SUM(hcdl) AS hcdl   FROM `produccion` WHERE desfase = \"$valor\"AND hora = \"$i2\" AND turno = \"$i3\"";
    $tabla1 = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql_produccion);
            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($tabla1))
                { // este llave abre donde muestra la sumatoria del real
                    // siento que aqui va el IF de sub encabezados cuando i = 0
            ?>
    <?php
    $SUMATORIA = 0 ;                
    // aqui hago consulta pra traer el HCDL calidad
    $sql_IDL = "SELECT SUM(cantidad_personas) AS cantidad_personas FROM `idl` WHERE fecha = \"$valor\" AND turno = \"$i3\" AND departamento = \"CALIDAD\"";
    $tabla2 = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql_IDL);
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($tabla2))
                { // este llave abre donde muestra la sumatoria del hc IDL
    $hcidl = round($row2['cantidad_personas']); 
                } // este llave cierra donde muestra la sumatoria del hc IDL    
    // aqui hago consulta pra traer el HCDL diagnostico
    $sql_IDL2 = "SELECT SUM(cantidad_personas) AS cantidad_personas FROM `idl` WHERE fecha = \"$valor\" AND turno = \"$i3\" AND departamento = \"DIAGNOSTICO\"";
    $tabla3 = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql_IDL2);
            while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($tabla3))
                { // este llave abre donde muestra la sumatoria del hc IDL
    $hcidl2 = round($row3['cantidad_personas']);    
                } // este llave cierra donde muestra la sumatoria del hc IDL    
    // aqui hago consulta pra traer el HCDL materiales
    $sql_IDL3 = "SELECT SUM(cantidad_personas) AS cantidad_personas FROM `idl` WHERE fecha = \"$valor\" AND turno = \"$i3\"  AND departamento = \"MATERIALES\"";
    $tabla4 = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql_IDL3);
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($tabla4))
                { // este llave abre donde muestra la sumatoria del hc IDL
    $hcidl3 = round($row2['cantidad_personas']);    
                } // este llave cierra donde muestra la sumatoria del hc IDL    
    // aqui hago consulta pra traer el HCDL materiales
    $sql_IDL4 = "SELECT SUM(cantidad_personas) AS cantidad_personas FROM `idl` WHERE fecha = \"$valor\" AND turno = \"$i3\"  AND departamento = \"PRODUCCION SOPORTE\"";
    $tabla5 = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql_IDL4);
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($tabla5))
                { // este llave abre donde muestra la sumatoria del hc IDL
    $hcidl4 = round($row2['cantidad_personas']);    
                } // este llave cierra donde muestra la sumatoria del hc IDL    
    $SUMATORIA = round($row1['hcdl']) + $hcidl + $hcidl2 + $hcidl3 + $hcidl4;
    $personas = 0;
    //consulto la cantidad de personas capturadas por supervisores como sistema tress
    $sql_tress = "SELECT hctress FROM `hc_tress` WHERE fecha = \"$valor\" AND turno = \"$i3\" AND hora = \"$i2\" ";
    $sql_tressconsulta = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql_tress);
            while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_tressconsulta))
                { // este llave abre donde muestra la sumatoria del hc IDL
    $personas = $row3['hctress'];   
                } // este llave cierra donde muestra la sumatoria del hc IDL    
    $deltaspersonas = $SUMATORIA - $personas ;
    if($personas > 1 AND $SUMATORIA > 1)
    {   
    $deltas = ( $SUMATORIA / $personas ) * 100 ;
    }
    if($personas == 0 )
    {
        $deltas = "0 %" ;
    }
    if($SUMATORIA == 0 )
    {
        $deltas = "0 %" ;
    }
    if($deltas == 100)
    {   
    $color = "background:#77DD77;";
    }
    if($deltas < 100)
    {   
    $color = "background:#FF6961;";
    }
    if($deltas > 100)
    {   
    $color = "background:#00a9ff;";
    }
    If ($deltas == "0 %" )
    {
    $color = "background:#F8F9F9;"; 
    }
    ?>              
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:20px;"><?php echo $i3." ".$i2 ?></td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:20px;"><?php echo  round($row1['hcdl']) ?></td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:20px;"><?php echo  $hcidl  ?></td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:20px;"><?php echo  $hcidl2  ?></td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:20px;"><?php echo  $hcidl3  ?></td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:20px;"><?php echo  $hcidl4  ?></td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:20px;"><?php echo  $SUMATORIA ?></td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:20px;"><?php echo  $personas ?></td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:20px;"><?php echo  $deltaspersonas  ?></td>
    <?php
    if($colores == "")
    {
    ?>  
        <td style="width:10%;font-size:20px;"><?php echo  round($deltas,2)." %" ?></td>
    <?php
    }
    if($colores == 1)
    {
    ?>  
    <td style="width:10%;font-size:20px;<?php echo $color ?>"><?php echo  round($deltas,2)." %" ?></td>
    <?php
    }
}// este llave cierra donde muestra la sumatoria del hc  real
        }// esta llave cierra donde el recorredor de hora
        ?>
    </tr> <!-- cierro renglon -->       
    <?php
            $i++ ; // aqui aumento el valor de I para que tome el siguiente valor del array $turno1horas    
    if ($i > $contadorarray)
    {
        $i=0;
    }
}// esta llave cierro donde el recorredor de hora
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Si no entendi mal, lo que puedes hacer es un contenedor (por ejemplo con un div) que este contenga las tablas, el contenedor contendrá en el css el "display:<flex| grid>" (yo suelo usar flex) entonces desde el navegador inspecciona el elemento del contenedor y puedes ir editando hasta que lo veas de la manera mas adecuada para ti

Answer (score 0):

Si te he entendido bien, pasa que al filtrar te "salta" una linea abajo el código. Creo que es por el siguiente código:

```
//
//Aqui abres una nueva linea (Abres <tr>)
//

<tr> <!-- abro renglon -->
<?php   
$i = 0; //inicializico en el valor de la llave en 0
while ($i < $contadorarray ) 
{ // esta llave abre donde el recorredor de hora
        $i2 = $turno1horas[$i];
        $i3 = $turnoarray[$i];
foreach ($fechadelwhile as $valor) 
    {
        if($i == 0 )
        {
       //
       //Al entrar aquí estás abriendo una nueva linea <tr>, por lo que en la visual salta de linea. 
       //  
        ?>
    <tr>
    <th style="width:20%;font-size:20px;" ></th>    
    <th style="width:8%;font-size:20px;" colspan="9"><?php echo $valor ?></th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>Turno Hora</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Produccion</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Calidad</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Diagnostico</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Materiales</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Soporte produccion</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Sumatoria</b>  </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Tress</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC Delta</b> </td>
        <td style="width:8%;font-size:10px;" ><b>HC  % Delta</b> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
```

Cuando filtras estas metiendo un nuevo  que ya había declarado más arriba, lo que provoca que salte de línea. Para solucionarlo deberias quitar la apertura y cierre de  dentro de ese ciclo y así se vería en la misma linea.